# Connecting Rooms

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've created a simple algorithm for a game I'm working on that creates a cave like structure. The algorithm outputs a 2 dimensional array of bits that represent the open area's. Example:

```
000000000000000000000000
010010000000000111100000
011110000000011111111000
011111110000011111111100
011111111001111111111110
011000000000001111000000
000000000000000000000000
```

(0's represent wall, 1's represent open areas)

The problem is that the algorithm can sometimes create a cave that has 2 non connected sections (as in the above example). I've written a function that gives me an array of arrays that contain all the x, y positions of the open spots for each area

My question is, given a number of lists that contain all of the x,y coordinates for each open area what is the fastest way to "connect" these area's be a corridor that is a minimum of 2 thickness wide.

(I'm writing this in javascript but even just pseudo code will help me out)

I've tried comparing the distances from every point in one area to every other area in another area, finding the two points that have the closest distance then cutting out a path from those 2 two points but this approach is way to slow I'm hoping there is another way.

Comment: Please edit your question to include both the approach you've tried, and where you got stuck.  Your current question could be rephrased "here's my problem, please write my code for me", which doesn't tend to go down well :)

Answer (score 1):

Given two caves A and B, choose a point x in A and y in B (at random will do, the two closest or locally closest is better). Drill a corridor of thickness 2 between A and B (use [Bresenham's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm)). If you have multiple disconnected caves, do the above for each edge (A,B) of the minimal spanning tree of the graph of all the caves (edge weight is the length of the corridor you'll drill if you choose this edge).

**Edit for the edit:** to approximate the distance between two caves, you can use [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing). It will return the global minimum for convex caves in O(n) rather than the naive O(n<sup>2</sup>). For non-convex caves, do multiple iterations of hill climbing with initial guess chosen in random.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exactly minimal solution, you can consider first building the frontiers of your caves and then applying O(nm) algorithm. This will eliminate the need to compare distances between interior points of your caves. Then as soon as you know the distances between each pair of caves, you build the minimal spanning tree, then you drill your tunnels.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know too much from your description, here are some hints I would consider:

How do you look for the pair of nearest points? Do you use a naive brute-force approach and thus obtain a run time of `O(n*n)`? Or are you using a more efficient variant [taking `O(n log n)` time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem#Planar_case)?

If you have obtained the closest points, I'd use a simple [line-drawing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm).

Another approach might be that you generate a structure that definitely has only one single connected area. Therefore you could do the following: First you take a random cell `(x,y)` and set it to `1`. Then, you traverse all it's neighbours and for each of them you randomly set it to `1` or leave it at `0`. For each cell set to `1`, you do the same, i.e. you traverse it's neighbours and set them randomly to `1` or `0`. This guarantees that you won't have two separate areas.

An algorithm to ensure this could be the following (in python):

```
def setCell(x,y,A):
    if x>=len(A) or y>=len(A[0]) or x<0 or y<0:
        return
    A[x][y] = 1

def getCell(x,y,A):
    if x>=len(A) or y>=len(A[0]) or x<0 or y<0:
        return 1
    return A[x][y]

def generate(height, width):
    A = [[0 for _ in xrange(width)] for _ in xrange(height)]
    from random import randint
    import Queue
    (x,y) = (randint(0, height-1), randint(0, width-1))
    setCell (x,y,A)
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put((x,y))
    while not q.empty():
        (x,y) = q.get()
        for (nx, ny) in [(x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)]:
            if randint(0,8)<=6:
                if getCell(nx,ny,A)==0:
                    setCell(nx,ny,A)
                    if randint(0,2)<=1:
                        q.put((nx,ny))
    return A

def printField(A):
    for l in A:
        for c in l:
            print (" " if c==1 else "X"), 
        print ""
```

Then `printField(generate(20,30))` does the job. Probably you'll have to adjust the parameters for random stuff so it fits your needs.